# How to multiply a matrix with a vector with preserving the shape of the matrix in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra

I know, there is a matmul function built in Tensorflow, but if I multiply a Matrix A with a vector v, I get a vector w as a result. But, what I need is, given the matrix A: [[a, b],[c,d]] and a vector v: [[e,f]], I want to get the matrix B: [[ae, bf], [ce, df]]. Both, the matrix and the vector, are tensors

Comment: You want element-wise multiplication after you reshape the vector to have same size as the matrix A with repeating the row. Or maybe do it iteratively row by row and rewrite it it A? I dont have experience with TF, but element-wie multiplication is what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `multiply` function of numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> v = np.array([5,6])
>>> np.multiply(a,v)
array([[ 5, 12],
           [15, 24]])
```

Optionally you could then use `.tolist()` to transform the numpy array to a Python list:

```
>>> np.multiply(a,v).tolist()
[[5, 12], [15, 24]]
```